# The smoke simulation doesn't look good in the rendered state. How can I change the render settings. so that the result looks better

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

In this project, I want to use smoke in the scene. Here are my render settings
[Rendersettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI7VF.png)
[image: Smoke]
[image: Smoke_Domain]

I don't know how to adjust the settings so that the end result looks better. Here's the rendered image[image: RenderdPicture]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Since I do not know what result you want to achieve (thick smoke, thin cigarette-like smoke, some kind of mist/fog?) I have no idea what a result that "looks better" could be. The only thing I can tell you, if your flow object is not moving really fast, the _Sampling Substeps_ of 100 are way too high. I'd go with 5 or 10 at max. But if you are not specifically going for low res smoke, the _Resolution Divisions_ of 66 on the domain are way too low for good results. You should also enable _Adaptive Domain_ to reduce the simulation time significantly, especially when you increase the resolution.